Use custom PHPmailer in wordpress for specific user IDs
I have a real estate website where agents can send properties to people who invest in this kind of properties.
However, some of the agents want to use their own email address sending the real estate data to the investors. So they have the possibility to store their own SMTP credentials in a woocommerce setting, which I implemented in the frontend of my site this afternoon. SMTP credentials are stored in user meta field as an array.
Now what I am trying to achieve is – in case an agent wants to use his own SMTP settings when distributing a property – to change the SMTP settings for outgoing mails from this specific agent.
What might be an approach / hook / filter that might work to overwrite the phpmailer settings under these specific circumstances with the users custom SMTP credentials?
I tried to use the following hook but I don't know, how I can get the $agent_id parameter INTO the phpmailer init function. get_current_user_id() will not work, since the distribution of the property is handled by post transition hook from "future" to "publish"
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'send_smtp_email' );
function send_smtp_email( $phpmailer ) 
{
    // How to get the $agent_id right here?
    $possiblearray = get_user_meta($agent_id, "smtpinfos", true);
    if(is_array($possiblearray))
    {
        $phpmailer->isSMTP();
        $phpmailer->Host = $smtpinfos["host"];
        $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = 'true';
        $phpmailer->Port = $smtpinfos["port"];
        $phpmailer->Username = $smtpinfos["nutzername"];
        $phpmailer->Password = $smtpinfos["nutzerpasswort"];
        $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = $smtpinfos["verschluesselung"];
        $phpmailer->From = $smtpinfos["frommail"];
        $phpmailer->FromName = $smtpinfos["fromname"];;
    }
    
}


Though you're using it, this doesn't have much to do with PHPMailer - that happens afterwards, and as you say it all hinges on getting that $agent_id, which is a very WordPress-specific question. Consequently, you might be better off asking on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com
